# Exception incompatible with throws clause

Tags: java, exception, throws

I am deveoloping small AOP standalone project there when i create my own exception it give this error exception incompatible with throws clause.please if any one can help appreciate very much.

This is the exception class i was written

```
package com.mtit.exceptions;

public class InsufficientAmountException extends Exception 
{
    /**
     * exception for handling invalid payment 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public InsufficientAmountException(String message)
    {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

This is the method

```
public void PaymentPatient(String PatientID,double discountRate,double ChargePerDay,double cashAmount) throws InsufficientAmountException 

{

    double totalAmount=CalculateTotalAmountPatient(PatientID,discountRate,ChargePerDay);

    if(cashAmount>=totalAmount)
    {
        double balance=cashAmount-totalAmount;
        System.out.println("Payment Succefully done your balance is "+"\t"+balance);

    }
    else
    {
        throw new InsufficientAmountException("Balance is insufficient");
    }
}
```

Here is the main method

```
try
    {
        //call the payment method i have written above
    }
    catch(InsufficientAmountException e)
    {
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

> error i am getting 
>   [image]
>
> main method

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{


    try
    {
        Payment();
    }
    catch(InsufficientAmountException e)
    {
        System.out.println("");
    }



}
public static void Payment()
{
    PatientService patientService=new PatientServiceImpl();
    Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter Patient ID");
    String id=scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter Discount rate");
    double discount=Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());

    System.out.println("Enter No of Days");
    int noOfDays=Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());

    double totalAmount=patientService.CalculateTotalAmountPatient(id, discount, noOfDays);

    System.out.println("Your total charge is"+"\t"+totalAmount);

    System.out.println("Would you like to do payment enter yes or no");
    String result=scanner.nextLine();

    if(result=="yes")
    {

        System.out.println("Enter charge per day");
        double ChargePerDay=Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Enter cash amount");
        double cashAmount=Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());

        patientService.PaymentPatient(id, discount, ChargePerDay, cashAmount);

    }
    else

    {
        System.out.println("Please do the payment with in 3 days to get rid from tax");
    }








}
```

Comment: I have mentioned the error with a screenshot

Comment: You've got a null pointer going on.

Comment: You need code that actually *throws* an exception within the `try`

Comment: The screenshot says `Payment()` whereas the code says `PaymentPatient`.

Comment: If you call PaymentPatient(String PatientID,do..... method this error disappears. In addition to that, use lowercase on methods first char

Comment: Post the code for `Main.Payment()`.

Comment: did you mean that  the paymentPatient method if else statement?with in if statement i have to write  "(cashamount-totalamount)>=0"

Comment: I have edited my question by adding main method i have written

Comment: Your `Payment()` method never throws `InsufficientAmountException`.

Comment: I have solved my question it was giving error because i call this method via a interface.so thank you so much those who have replied me

Answer (score 0):

Because the method `Payment()` isn't declared with `throws InsufficientAmountException`, your `try...catch` block is useless, that's why you get the error. Either remove the `try...catch` block, or modify `Payment()` to throw `InsufficientAmountException`.